# "backward-same-syntax" in Emacs

Tags: emacs

I found great function "forward-same-syntax" for emacs that very closely emulate "ctrl + right arrow" in atom/PyCharm/any other modern text editors, but I could not find "backward-same-syntax" analog. How can I access this function?

Or maybe there is a plugin/another way to completely emulate ctrl+arrows behaviour from modern text editors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with most movement functions in emacs, `forward-same-syntax` takes an optional prefix argument, that when negative, causes the function to operate backwards.  This is cleary described in the docstring of that function.

So, the `backward-same-syntax` analog is simply `(forward-same-syntax -n)`, or <kbd>C-u</kbd>`-n`<kbd>M-x</kbd>`forward-same-syntax`, where `n` is any number.  Of course, you could wrap that in a function and bind it to a key if you wanted to (see `backward-sexp` for a simple wrapper example).